# Defining logic in class constructor to modify instance variable based on other constructor arguments in python

Tags: python, properties, getter-setter

i have a python class in which i have few arguments sent to constructor as below.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        if b<10:
            self.a = a*2
```

I know that, constructors are just meant to initialize variable's and there should be no logic inside a constructor. But, if not this way, how can i set value of "a" variable based a logic with "b" variable. I tried to use property. following is my code

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    @property
    def a(self):
        self._a
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        if self.b < 10:
            self._a = value*2
        else:
            self._a = value
```

But, problem is that, setter is not called when initializing with a constructor. So, how can i solve this problem of modifying the default setting of few variable inside a constructor

Comment: how about doing logic before the constructor?   `if b < 10: a = a*2 Test(a, b)`?

Comment: There's no such rule. Put whatever you like into init, as long as it's clear.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, is there good way to do this, may be overriding default getter setter ?

Comment: Thing is, i have to set almost 10 other instance variables based on one of the parameter.Also, the logic is not just one if-else, its a ladder of if-else loops.  so, i thought it would be cleaner if i can make use of some construct so that logic would be applied to all the variables i want

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas, problem is, its not just one variable that i want to update. i want to update multiple variables based on b

Comment: `self.a` was never called since it's missing the `()` at the end?

Comment: I think i get it, @Miket25, thanks. i think, instead of doing self.a = a, i should do self.a(a). am i right

Comment: The second example, the setter method doesn't know what `self.b` until it become set. Swap the ordering of the two lines in the `__init__` so that `b` is set before `a`. Note that `a` and `_a` will be different.